# OpenMP gives (core dumped)

Tags: c, openmp

I have loop which I want to parallelize with OpenMP. when I compile with `gcc -o prog prog.c -lm -fopenmp` I get no errors. But when I execute it, I get `segmentation fault(core dumped)`. The problem surely comes from the OpenMP commands because the program works when I delete the `#pragma`...

Here is the parallel loop:

```
ix = (i-1)%ILIGNE+1;
iy = (i-1)/ILIGNE+1;
k = 1;
# pragma omp parallel for private(j,jx,jy,r,R,voisin) shared(NTOT,k,i,ix,iy) num_threads(2) schedule(auto)
for(j = 1;j <= NTOT;j++){
  if(j != i){
    jx = (j-1)%ILIGNE+1;
    jy = (j-1)/ICOLONE+1;
    r[k][0] = (jx-ix)*a;
    r[k][1] = (jy-iy)*a;
    R[k] = sqrt(pow(r[k][0],2.0)+pow(r[k][1],2.0));
    voisin[k] = j;
    k++;
  }
}
```

I tried to change the stack size to unlimited but it doesn't fix the problem. Please tell me if it is about a memory leak or a race condition or something else? and thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, be careful when you make an array private.

If you allocated it as a static array
e.g.
`int R[5]` or something similar then that's fine, each thread gets its own personal copy :).

If you `malloc` these however
e.g.:

`int R = malloc(5*sizeof(int));`
then it will act as a shared array regardless of whether you define it as private (which could potentially lead to undefined behaviour, segfaults, jibberish in the array etc).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your code does, but I'm pretty sure the OpenMP version is wrong. Indeed, you parallelised over the `j` loop, but the heart of your algorithm revolves around the `k`, which is loosely derived from `j` and `i` (which is not presented here BTW).

So when you distribute your `j` indexes across your OpenMP threads, they all start from a different value of `j`, but all from the same value of `k` which is shared. From that, `k` is incremented quite randomly and the accesses to the various arrays using `k` are very very likely to generate segmentation faults.

Moreover, arrays `r`, `R` and `voisin` shouldn't be declared `private` if one want the parallelisation to have any effect.

Finally, C loops like this `for(j = 1;j <= NTOT;j++)` look utterly suspicious to me for off-by-one accesses... Shouldn't that be rather `for(j = 0;j < NTOT;j++)`? (just mentioning this since the initial value of `k` is 1 as well...)

Bottom line is that you'd probably better define `k` from `j`'s value with `k = j<i ? j : j-1` instead of trying to increment it inside the code.
Assuming all the rest is correct, this might be a valid version:

```
ix = (i-1)%ILIGNE+1;
iy = (i-1)/ILIGNE+1;
# pragma omp parallel for private(j,jx,jy,k) num_threads(2) schedule(auto)
for(j = 1;j <= NTOT;j++){
  if(j != i){
    k = j<i ? j : j-1;
    jx = (j-1)%ILIGNE+1;
    jy = (j-1)/ICOLONE+1;
    r[k][0] = (jx-ix)*a;
    r[k][1] = (jy-iy)*a;
    R[k] = sqrt(pow(r[k][0],2.0)+pow(r[k][1],2.0));
    voisin[k] = j;
  }
}
```

Still, be careful with the C indexing from 0 to size-1, not from 1 to size...